# Cannot GET /ok error when using .get in express/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use .get so I can fetch from it from an html file but it just has not found error.

```
<script> 
document.getElementById("runCliTool").addEventListener("click", function() {
  fetch('/ok', {
        method: 'GET' 
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const displayBox = document.getElementById("dataDisplayBox");
        displayBox.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    })
    
});
```

map.html file,

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'sensitive.env' });
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(express.json()); 

app.listen(PORT);

app.get('/ok', (req, res) => {
    exec('node cli-tool.js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Failed to execute CLI tool', error: error.toString() });
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        if (stderr) console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        res.send({ message: 'CLI tool executed successfully', output: stdout });
    });
});
```

server.js file

If I set the path of the fetch in map.html to server.js, it detects the file but for some reason doing app.get('ok', does not create a pathway to that and it returns not found in the fetch from my html file.